# Cannot resolve method 'mapId' in 'GoogleMapOptions'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

I am trying to add my modified map to app but
`MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions().mapId(getResources().getString(R.string.map_id)));` not working. Error type: "Cannot resolve method 'mapId' in 'GoogleMapOptions'"
I did everything what is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-based-map-styling but still not working.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/GoogleMapOptions

Comment: I googled the class and found an API description that did not include the method whereas the API you linked does include it.  I could not find version info on either page.  Consider trying to update the library to a more recent version.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for help! I will describe it below.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I wanted do that on other version of google maps API. I missed one sentence:

> "Cloud-based maps styling features are not yet available in the Google Play Services Maps Library. To test them, use the standalone Beta Maps SDK for Android.
> For instructions on how to download the beta SDK, see Installing Maps SDK for Android v.3.1.0 BETA"

It worked for me while:

- change api to the newest version
- update Android Studio (?)

Comment: Can you please add a link to the docs that you have mentioned?
edit: Looks like this available in v18.0.0 of the maps SDK https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases#2021-10-27
However I  am having a hard time, the code sample mentioned in docs isn't works, Perhaps I am missing something.